# If I connect 2 android devices via WiFi-Direct - can one share its Internet connection with the other?

Tags: android, sdk, wifi-direct

I am building an SDK for a client to connect 2 android devices for exchanging data (strings, commands...) via various channels, such as Bluetooth, USB cable, WiFi.

One of the devices is a standard android phone, with a SIM card and data, thus able to access the internet. The other has no SIM card.

Currently using WiFi I am opening a HotSpot on the phone device, and so the non-SIM device can access the internet via the HotSpot.

Now my client wants me to connect via WiFi-Direct, too.
So my question is - once I connect the two devices via WiFi-Direct, will I be able to access the internet on the non-SIM device, using the SIM/data on the "normal" phone?

Thx

Comment: No time to try that out?

Comment: Hi, if you mean did I try this "manually" then yes - tried and it does not seem to work. But since I am writing code to work with WiFi-Direct, IU thought I's ask uf there is something I can do in my program to allow this.

Answer (score 3):

Well, Wi-Fi direct can create hotspot independent of the legacy Wi-Fi hotspot BUT this hotspot doesn't share internet and any request to external ip will be dropped.
But for android  you can use NetShare app to do that, you can download it from 
[here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kha.prog.mikrotik&referrer=utm_source%3Dstack_connect).

it works as follows:

• in the client side NetShare use the vpn service to catch all internet traffic of the device and send them to NetShare in the server device and wait for the response.

• in the server side NetShare run a server with specific port to receive the internet packets sent from the client side in 
previous step, it send these packets to the internet, after receiving the reponse from the internet it will send these responses to the NetShare in the client side which in turn provide it to the back to the client device.

for more details see the [official website](https://netshare.app/?utm_source=stack&utm_medium=stack&utm_campaign=stack)

Comment: Thanks. Will look into it. Problem is not sure my client would want to install 3rd party apps. Will see...

Comment: Not a problem, use the proxy which doesn't need to install the app in the other device but you will need to setup the proxy in it as explained in the help section of the app.

Comment: Thx. I will look into this, and let my client know.